# How can I avoid reading old or missing records in replica due to replication lag between master/slave database?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, database-replication, master-slave

I’m using the AWS Aurora Postgres database which has a master and replica setup. In one part of my application, the system has to read from `TableA` right after inserting or updating a record on the same table. Since it’s reading from the replica, there is a slight latency between the master and the read replica. Thus, I’m not always getting the latest data and sometimes a record may appear missing because the replica hasn’t sync the record from master yet.

What I’ve done now is to direct all the read query in this part of the application to read directly from `TableA` in master after the insert/update query. However, due to the number of reads it is making from this query, the load on the master instance spiked up by a lot.

Suddenly, there is twice the number of IOPS made to the master in this part of the application. If there were 100,000 insert/updates to `TableA`, there would now be another 1000,000 reads from `TableA` on the master instance too! Meanwhile, the replica has very little load but I cannot shift this read operation to it just because of the replication lag. This results in not fully utilising the replica.

Are there any strategies I can use to prevent this issue that I’m having?

While reading directly from master works, it doesn't sound right to be hitting the master with so many read operations.

I’m using Node and Sequelize in my application.

Comment: Can the master keep up with the load?  If you do need to provision more IOPS, I don't think you get a price break for provisioning them on the replica rather than on the master.  There is nothing wrong with having a replica exist solely for failover purposes.

Comment: @jjanes Well, the master still has sufficient IOPS. The only issue is with the CPU load. The additional read operations is taking a toll on the CPU load of the master.

Answer (score 1):

Streaming replication is not really a load balancing device.

If you want data modifications to be visible on the standby immediately, you have to

1. use synchronous streaming replication by adding the standby to `synchronous_standby_names` on the primary (but beware that that reduces the total availability!)
2. set `synchronous_commit = remote_apply` on the primary server

This will only work well if the network latency is low and you don't have a lot of writing transactions, so it is probably right out with a hosted database.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only work with async replication in aurora.